# Handle Extra Coma in CSV from code level

Tags: controller, csv

[image]

in Certification column there are 3 certificate which are mention as 1x,2x,3x
when i parse csv it shown an error An error has occured reading the CSV fileList index out of bounds: 2

how to handle extra comma's from code level

here is my class code

```
public class ExcelFileUploader 
{
    public string nameFile{get;set;}
    public Blob contentFile{get;set;}
    String[] filelines = new String[]{};
    List<Lead> leadtoupload;
    public ExcelFileUploader() {

    }

    public Pagereference ReadFile()
    {
        try{

                nameFile =blobToString( contentFile,'ISO-8859-1');
                filelines = nameFile.split('\n');
                leadtoupload = new List<Lead>();
                for (Integer i=1;i<filelines.size();i++)
                {
                    String[] inputvalues = new String[]{};
                    inputvalues = filelines[i].split(',');
                    Lead a = new Lead();
                    a.FirstName = inputvalues[0];
                    a.LastName = inputvalues[1];
                    a.Experience__c= inputvalues[2];     
                    a.Current_CTC__c=  decimal.valueOf(inputvalues[3]);
                    a.Expected_CTC__c= decimal.valueOf(inputvalues[4]);
                    a.Company= inputvalues[5];
                    a.City__c = inputvalues[6];
                    a.MobilePhone = inputvalues[7];
                    a.Email = inputvalues[8];
                    a.Notice_Period__c =inputvalues[9];
                    a.Certified__c =  inputvalues[10];
                    string[] fulldt = inputvalues[11].split(' ');
                    string[] dt = fulldt[0].split('/');
                    string SchedTime = dt[2]+'-'+dt[1]+'-'+dt[0]+' '+fulldt[1]+':00'; 
                    system.debug('schedtime-->'+SchedTime );
                    a.Scheduled_Time__c = datetime.valueOf(SchedTime);

                    if(inputvalues[12] == 'yes' || inputvalues[12] =='YES'){
                     a.Interested__c = true;
                    }else {
                        a.Interested__c = false;
                    }
                    a.Scheduled_By__c = inputvalues[13];

                    leadtoupload.add(a);
                }
         }
         catch(Exception e){
                 ApexPages.Message errormsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured reading the CSV file'+e.getMessage());
                ApexPages.addMessage(errormsg);
         }       

        try{
            insert leadtoupload;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ApexPages.Message errormsg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'An error has occured inserting the records'+e.getMessage());
            ApexPages.addMessage(errormsg);
        }    
        return null;
    }

    public List<Lead> getuploadedLeads()
    {
        if (leadtoupload!= NULL)
            if (leadtoupload.size() > 0)
                return leadtoupload;
            else
                return null;                    
        else
            return null;
    }  

    public static String blobToString(Blob input, String inCharset){
        String hex = EncodingUtil.convertToHex(input);
        System.assertEquals(0, hex.length() & 1);
        final Integer bytesCount = hex.length() >> 1;
        String[] bytes = new String[bytesCount];
        for(Integer i = 0; i < bytesCount; ++i)
            bytes[i] =  hex.mid(i << 1, 2);
        return EncodingUtil.urlDecode('%' + String.join(bytes, '%'), inCharset);
    }         
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code was taken from the code samples found [Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Code_Samples#Parse_a_CSV_with_APEX).  Maybe you can take a look at it and use it to modify your code.

```
public static List<List<String>> parseCSV(String contents,Boolean skipHeaders) {
    List<List<String>> allFields = new List<List<String>>();

    // replace instances where a double quote begins a field containing a comma
    // in this case you get a double quote followed by a doubled double quote
    // do this for beginning and end of a field
    contents = contents.replaceAll(',"""',',"DBLQT').replaceall('""",','DBLQT",');
    // now replace all remaining double quotes - we do this so that we can reconstruct
    // fields with commas inside assuming they begin and end with a double quote
    contents = contents.replaceAll('""','DBLQT');
    // we are not attempting to handle fields with a newline inside of them
    // so, split on newline to get the spreadsheet rows
    List<String> lines = new List<String>();
    try {
        lines = contents.split('\n');
    } catch (System.ListException e) {
        System.debug('Limits exceeded?' + e.getMessage());
    }
    Integer num = 0;
    for(String line&nbsp;: lines) {
        // check for blank CSV lines (only commas)
        if (line.replaceAll(',','').trim().length() == 0) break;

        List<String> fields = line.split(',');  
        List<String> cleanFields = new List<String>();
        String compositeField;
        Boolean makeCompositeField = false;
        for(String field&nbsp;: fields) {
            if (field.startsWith('"') && field.endsWith('"')) {
                cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));
            } else if (field.startsWith('"')) {
                makeCompositeField = true;
                compositeField = field;
            } else if (field.endsWith('"')) {
                compositeField += ',' + field;
                cleanFields.add(compositeField.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));
                makeCompositeField = false;
            } else if (makeCompositeField) {
                compositeField +=  ',' + field;
            } else {
                cleanFields.add(field.replaceAll('DBLQT','"'));
            }
        }

        allFields.add(cleanFields);
    }
    if (skipHeaders) allFields.remove(0);
    return allFields;       
}
```

As @sfdcfox pointed out, you probably want to avoid using `DBLQT` as a magic string and replace it with something else that is less likely to be found in a CSV file.

Comment: My only complaint about using DBLQT as a magic string is that it's entirely possible that this string might already be in there somewhere, messing up the logic. I personally like to use "☺" (Alt+1 in Windows), because it's almost guaranteed not to be anywhere in the code.

Comment: @DougB -doesn't the replaceAll() often run into `regex too complicated` error when CSV file is of even moderate size?